# How do I design a class hierarchy for parent/child/grandparent?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, composition

This recursive function (`search_Bases`) would hopefully iterate through each base class and `__init__` it. How do I refer to each class's `self`, without actually using `self`? I've tried a couple things but I can't figure it out. When I change the `Child()` class up to do something similar, it works. So I have no clue what to do next.

```
def search_Bases(child=0):
    if child.__bases__:
        for parent in child.__bases__:
            parent.__init__(self) # <-----I can't figure out how to initiate the class
                                  # without referring to 'self'.... 
            search_Bases(parent)


class Female_Grandparent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.grandma_name = 'Grandma'

class Male_Grandparent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.grandpa_name = 'Grandpa'

class Female_Parent(Female_Grandparent, Male_Grandparent):
    def __init__(self):
        Female_Grandparent.__init__(self)
        Male_Grandparent.__init__(self)
        self.female_parent_name = 'Mother'

class Male_Parent(Female_Grandparent, Male_Grandparent):
    def __init__(self):
        Female_Grandparent.__init__(self)
        Male_Grandparent.__init__(self)
        self.male_parent_name = 'Father'

class Child(Female_Parent, Male_Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Female_Parent.__init__(self)
        Male_Parent.__init__(self)

        #search_Bases(Child)


child = Child()
print child.grandma_name
```

Comment: Here is an example of the edited child class:                   class Child(Female_Parent, Male_Parent):
    def __init__(self):

        parents = [Female_Parent,Male_Parent]
        for parent in parents:
            parent.__init__(self)                                                                                                                    It seems to work just fine. I don't see how its different.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What error do you get, or what isn't it doing that you expect it to do?  Also please remove all the extraneous blank lines from your code, they make it needlessly long.

Comment: Second thought...I think I know...I never realy instantiated the class, i just referred to it by Class.__bases__.....

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve with your search_Base function? you are already calling all the inits on your child object. In python you rarely have to call `__init__` (except in another `__init__` method).

Comment: I'm sorry. I threw this up with only a few minutes left online. I did not properly edit it or fully describe what I was after. I left the init def in each class even though I wanted code without it, which did not help my case. But I found a way to deal with it. Basically, I wanted to init each parent without doing so explicitly in each class def. But, doing it explicitly is better anyways (and maybe the only way). Sorry for the confusing post. I'll use better code etiquette in the future. :P

Comment: A more complicated version using two-way association, which you don't need: [How to link parent and children to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092970/how-to-link-parent-and-children-to-each-other)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you properly understand class inheritance. In Python,

```
class Female_Parent(Female_Grandparent, Male_Grandparent):
    def __init__(self):
```

means that `Female_Parent` IS-A `Male_Grandparent`, which seems unlikely. What you meant to say was

```
class Female_Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, female_grandparent, male_grandparent):
```

This also has problems, in that the role changes depending on who is asking - by definition, a `Male_Grandparent` (of his grandchildren) is also a `Male_Parent` (of his children) who is also a `Child` (of his parents).

You can boil all your classes down to

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, mother, father):
```

and derive further relationships from there. This gives a much simpler structure, without the point-of-view contradictions, but still results in problems evaluating further relationships because a given person's links only go "up" - a given person knows who their parents were, but can't identify their children.

You could keep a list of all your Persons and search the list each time (like a mother going around the kindergarten saying, "Are you my child? You? Are YOU my child?") but this seems very inefficient.

Instead, you can make each relationship two-way - each parent has a list of all their children and each child has a list of all their parents. It makes adding and removing people a little harder, but is well worth it.

The following is longer than I like but as short as I could make it; it should suit your needs much better!

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, sex, parents=None, children=None):
        """
        Create a Person
        """
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex    # 'M' or 'F'

        self.parents = set()
        if parents is not None:
            for p in parents:
                self.add_parent(p)

        self.children = set()
        if children is not None:
            for c in children:
                self.add_child(c)

    def add_parent(self, p):
        self.parents.add(p)
        p.children.add(self)

    def add_child(self, c):
        self.children.add(c)
        c.parents.add(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Person('{}', '{}')".format(self.name, self.sex)

    #
    # Immediate relationships
    #
    # Each fn returns a set of people who fulfill the stated relationship
    #

    def _parent(self):
        return self.parents

    def _sibling(self):
        return set().union(*(p.children for p in self.parents)) - set([self])

    def _child(self):
        return self.children

    def _female(self):
        if self.sex=='F':
            return set([self])
        else:
            return set()

    def _male(self):
        if self.sex=='M':
            return set([self])
        else:
            return set()

    def relation(self, *rels):
        """
        Find the set of all people who fulfill the stated relationship

        Ex:
            self.relation("parent", "siblings")     # returns all aunts and uncles of self
        """
        # start with the current person
        ps = set([self])

        for rel in rels:
            # each argument is either a function or a string
            if callable(rel):
                # run the function against all people in the current set
                #   and collect the results to a new set
                ps = set().union(*(rel(p) for p in ps))
            else:
                # recurse to evaluate the string
                do = Person._relations[rel]
                ps = set().union(*(p.relation(*do) for p in ps))

        return ps

    def print_relation(self, *rels):
        print ', '.join(str(p) for p in self.relation(*rels))

#
# Extended relationships
#
# Supplies the necessary information for Person.relation() to do its job -
# Each key refers to a recursive function tree (nodes are string values, leaves are functions)
#
# (Unfortunately this table cannot be created until the Person class is finalized)
#
Person._relations = {
    "parent":        (Person._parent,),
    "mother":        (Person._parent, Person._female),
    "father":        (Person._parent, Person._male),
    "sibling":       (Person._sibling,),
    "sister":        (Person._sibling, Person._female),
    "brother":       (Person._sibling, Person._male),
    "child":         (Person._child,),
    "daughter":      (Person._child, Person._female),
    "son":           (Person._child, Person._male),
    "grandparent":   ("parent", "parent"),
    "grandmother":   ("parent", "mother"),
    "grandfather":   ("parent", "father"),
    "aunt":          ("parent", "sister"),
    "uncle":         ("parent", "brother"),
    "cousin":        ("parent", "sibling", "child"),
    "niece":         ("sibling", "daughter"),
    "nephew":        ("sibling", "son"),
    "grandchild":    ("child", "child"),
    "grandson":      ("child", "son"),
    "granddaughter": ("child", "daughter")
}
```

and now, in action:

```
mm  = Person('Grandma', 'F')
mf  = Person('Grandpa', 'M')
m   = Person('Mom', 'F', [mm, mf])
fm  = Person('Nana', 'F')
ff  = Person('Papi', 'M')
f   = Person('Dad', 'M', [fm, ff])
me  = Person('Me', 'M', [m, f])
s   = Person('Sis', 'F', [m, f])
joe = Person('Brother-in-law', 'M')
s1  = Person('Andy', 'M', [s, joe])
s2  = Person('Betty', 'F', [s, joe])
s3  = Person('Carl', 'M', [s, joe])

me.print_relation("grandmother")    # returns 'Nana, Grandma'
me.print_relation("nephew")         # returns 'Andy, Carl'
```

Comment: I wasn't really trying to make classes to represent families. I named them the way I did to simulate the idea of dna sorta: The child is directly formed from the dna of the parents and so is a copy of the two combined. They ARE their parents in a way....but yeh, you did show me some useful stuff I can use, so thank you. :)

Comment: I wasn't really trying to make classes to represent families. I named them the way I did as a convention, but my idea was to simulate the idea of dna sorta: The child is directly formed from the dna of the parents and so is a copy of the two combined. They ARE their parents in a way. Again, it wasn't really meant to model a family tree. I just used it as a naming convention. But yeh, you did show me some useful stuff I can use, so thank you. :) P.S, Please ignore the earlier comment. :)